I don't know how to use potential energy formula of transverse wave

This is the formula of potential energy of transverse wave

and this is the picture of transverse wave. If I know that potential energy of transverse wave right, potential energy at x=2m has to be maximum. but, I know this is wrong conclusion because x=2m in the picture has zero potential energy. I think I don't understand the potential energy of transverse wave. How can I explain the fact that potential energy becomes 0 at x=2m using the potential energy formula I posted above?

Actually, the potential energy is maximum at $x=2$m. This might seem counterintuitive. Note that even the kinetic energy is maximum at $x=2$m, or at every node in this diagram.
Think about it: Elastic potential energy is maximum when the elongation in the body we are referring to is maximum(generally). If you observe the wave at $x=2$m, its $x$ coordinate is $0$. Which might make you think that its potential energy is $0$, but think further. At $x=2$m, every point around it has a velocity either upwards or downwards. This acts as a pulling force. It stretches the point with zero $x$ velocity in both directions. You can use this analysis for every point whose $x$ coordinate is zero.
Further, consider the points whose $y$ value is maximum. At this point, all points around it try to pull that point downwards. As it moves downwards, see that that exact $dl$ length gets elongated. Hence we can conclude that its potential energy is minimum at all extremas. Even its kinetic energy is $0$ at those points.
This is quite counterintuitive at first, but string waves act like this.
Even the equation in the picture says the same, mathematically.
